# How can I resolve the "cout was not declared in this scope" error?

Tags: c++, scope, header, namespaces, declaration

just a simple program but can anyone point out why this error is occuring, (i am using dev C++ version 5.11)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

class animal
{
 public :
    void sound();

     void eat() ;

};
void animal::eat()
{
        cout<<"i eat animal food" ; 


}


void animal::sound()
{
        cout<<"i sound like an animal" ;

     }

void main()
{
    animal a ;
    a.sound()
    a.eat()
    getch()
}
```

the error is coming like this:

```
In member function 'void animal::eat()':
15  4   C:\Users\chetna\Documents\Untitled1.cpp [Error] 'cout' was not declared in this scope
1   0   C:\Users\chetna\Documents\Untitled1.cpp In file included from C:\Users\chetna\Documents\Untitled1.cpp
```

Comment: The error is quite clear, the compiler doesn't know what `cout` is. You need to include the appropriate header, as well you need to reference the namespace it belongs in (`std`)

Comment: @ChrisMM Although the error is quite clear, the actual solution is not apparent from it. Neither of the two things required follow directly from that error. Please don't post answers as comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, stop using the old Borland C++ et al.

Use a modern standards compliant C++ compiler (g++, clang, Microsoft Visual Studio) instead.

Do not use conio.h, it is a very old compiler specific library, not a standard one.

Do not use stdio.h it is not a bad library, but it declares several C functions, not C++ ones.

Declare your main function as

```
int main()
```

not `void main()`, because standard C++ needs the main function to return an int (0 for success).

Instead of using `cout`, use `std::cout` , because it is an object representing the standard output defined inside the `std` namespace.

Answer (score 3):

At least you have to include

```
#include <iostream>
```

and

```
using namespace std;
```

The name `cout` is declared in the namespace `std`. So either use the using directive as shown above or use a qualified name (that is better) like

```
std::cout<<"i eat animal food" ;
```

An alternative approach is to use a using declaration. For example

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;

//...
void animal::eat()
{
        cout<<"i eat animal food" ; 
}
```

And remove this directive

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

Also place semicolons

```
a.sound();
a.eat();
getch();
```

Pay attention to that the function main shall be declared like

```
int main()
```

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily advocate `using namespace std` in an answer.

Comment: @sweenish For starters there is written "at least" in my answer. Secondly he is a beginner that starts to learn C++. All books on C++ for beginners usually use the using directive. So there is nothing wrong for a beginner to use the directive.

Comment: I figured this response was coming, and I **generally** agree with it. But whenever I've taught intro, that line of code comes with a 1 minute spiel about being beginner "friendly" and that they shouldn't get too attached to it. In fact, I'm not planning on using that line in the future as it just creates a pain point for too many students in future classes. As an answer, advocating that line with no explanation has the potential to imply that it's required. I find the "at least" to be an inadequate guard.